# Saving Flickr Photosets

Tags: php, json, flickr

How can I save each photoset to a folder on my server where the the name of the folder would be the title of the photoset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PHPFlickr](http://code.google.com/p/phpflickr/). It makes it easy to interface to the Flickr API.